# Flex Mobile Why persistNavigatorState="true" and stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT) don't mix?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

Why can't I use **persistNavigatorState="true"** and **stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT)** together in initializing program.

```
<s:View ...creationComplete="init()">
```

> protected  function init():void   {
>
> stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT);
>   }

```
    [SWF] Main.swf - 3,394,828 bytes after decompression
    TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at views::Try01/init()[C:\Users\James\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\myProgram\src\views\Try01.mxml:19]
    at views::Try01/___Try01_View1_creationComplete()[C:\Users\James\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\myProgram\src\views\Try01.mxml:4]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13128]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1818]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1090]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateNow()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8067]
    at spark.components::ViewNavigator/commitNavigatorAction()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\ViewNavigator.as:1878]
    at spark.components::ViewNavigator/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\ViewNavigator.as:1236]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8209]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:597]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:783]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

Whenever I enable persistNavigatorState, my program won't run. Is there a way to use both together? Thanks

[Line 4] `creationComplete="init()"`

```
    protected  function init():void {


[Line 19]  stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Won't Run" ? Do you get an error?  OR does the app not load?  Or does it load and immediately crash?  Which platform are you targeting?  Does the behavior exist in the emulator, or on a device?

Comment: Running on Mobile emulator, I got a lot of errors and the emulator just hang can't event build it to try on any device. If you wanted to know the errors, let me know and I will post it. (Using FB 4.5.1)

Comment: Lots of issues w/ the emulator.  But, if you want the vaguest form of direction, you'll have to post the error.

Comment: errors posted, pls refer above

Comment: Fantastic.  So; what code is in Try01.mxml at line 19?  What is at line 4?  Are you trying to access the stage before it is set?

Comment: pls refer above. All I try to do is make the Stage change to Portrait in creationComplete (or is there a better way to do this?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the creationComplete event fires before the stage is accessable.  Using persistNavigatorState changes the startup behavior of your application a bit by first fetching your navigator's state info from the persistence cache. This line in the Flex docs is quite telling: *when the application restarts, only the state of the current ViewNavigator is restored*. Also, the stage in flex is not accessable until an object is added to the displayList.  So if you call `setAspectRatio` when the stage is empty, you will get a null obj reference.

Instead of using stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT) on creationComplete, you can try setting including `<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>` in your app.xml.

Or, you could listen for the addedToStage event in your view, and call `stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT)` in the event handler. That way you know for sure that the stage is available.

References:

- [Adobe Enable Persistence in Mobile App](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSb0a29bf92525419c-54dd253312afbec3ecb-8000.html)
- [Flexponential - orientation and deviceOrientation in Flex Mobile apps](http://flexponential.com/2011/11/06/orientation-and-deviceorientation-in-flex-mobile-apps/)
- [Anselm Bradford - After CreationComplete A Flex Component’s Stage Property Is… What? Null?](http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2008/08/22/after-creationcomplete-a-flex-components-stage-property-is-what-null/)

Comment: I have been trying to use a lot of difference types of event listener but didn't try addedToStage. Thanks for the great suggestion, it works!

Comment: +1 for mention of addedToStage event.  I can't believe that one didn't pop into my mind before.